# Python - CBOR with NetworkX Graph

Tags: python, networkx, cbor

Is it possible to store a Networkx Graph object in a CBOR object (serialize the data through CBOR)?  I have fairly large NetworkX graphs and need to serialize and store for further analysis.  Pickle seems too slow and creates too large of a file.  I'm not seeing enough documentation on CBOR to properly determine if my task is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the performance of CBOR. From what I read it seems to be quite efficient with json.
So I tested the serialization and it works perfectly:

```
from networkx.readwrite import json_graph
import cbor

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from([('a1', 'a2', 1.0), ('a2', 'a3', 0.5), 
                           ('a3', 'a5', 1.0), ('a4', 'a8', 1.0), ('a8', 'a9', 0.8)])

# Serialize graph
res = json_graph.node_link_data(G)  # export Networkx to JSON
serialized = cbor.dumps(res)  # serialize in binary format

deserialized = cbor.loads(serialized)  # deserialize
H = json_graph.node_link_graph(deserialized)  # Get back to original graph
```